# Group collection by first letter

Tags: magento-1.8, group

I am trying to return a collection of brands in Magento that are grouped by the first letter of the title attribute. I have this but it results in a 500 error on the page in question:

```
public function getBrandGroupedCollection()
    {

        $brandsCollection = Mage::getModel('shopbybrand/brand')->getCollection();
        $brandsCollection
            ->addStatusFilter()
            ->setOrder('title', 'asc')
        ;
        $brandsCollection->getSelect()->group(substr('title',0,1)); 
        return $brandsCollection;
    }
```

How can I group the results by the first letter of the "title" attribute?

Answer (score 1):

I think you'd have to perform an expression on the query into a new column that you may *then* aggregate on. The way you're doing it in the sample above would try to group by the results by the value of a column named `t` which does not exist.

Try this:

```
public function getBrandGroupedCollection()
{

    $brandsCollection = Mage::getModel('shopbybrand/brand')->getCollection();

    $brandsCollection
        ->addStatusFilter()
        ->setOrder('title', 'asc')
    ;

    $brandsCollection->getSelect()
        ->columns(new Zend_Db_Expr('SUBSTR(title, 1, 1) AS first_letter'))
        ->group('first_letter');

    // Optional debug output
    //echo $brandsCollection->getSelect()->assemble(); exit;

    return $brandsCollection;
}
```

So we rely on this dynamic column `first_letter` to be generated using MySQL's built-in `SUBSTR` [[ref](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substr)]. Notice that its index is 1-based (not zero). **Now** you can group by this column.

Note: Not sure if it will make a difference, but you could base your ordering then on `first_letter` instead of `title`

Comment: Hi and thanks! I think this brings me much closer. When I added the column and grouped by it I get another 500 error. Here are the details of the log: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'first_letter' in 'group statement'";i:1;s:3791:"#0 /public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)

Comment: The column must not be getting added (see line 11 of my code above) to the query. Verify the query by dumping it before you return the collection. See my updated answer for how to do that. Then post the output query.

Comment: Output from the debug is this: SELECT `main_table`.*, SUBSTR(title, 1, 1) AS first_letter FROM `shopbybrand_brand_flat` AS `main_table` WHERE (brand_status = 1) GROUP BY `first_letter`

Comment: I did some debugging on the added line and discovered that the column is being added. If I remove "->group('first_letter');" everything works fine. That must be where the problem is...